# Plot vector as barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a vector:

```
x<-c(1,1,1,1,2,3,5,1,1,1,2,4,9)
y<-length(x)
```

I would like to plot this such that each value is plotted separately instead of plotting counts.

So basically each value should be represented separately in the plot where the length of the x axis is equal to `y` and each value is plotted on the y axis.

How can this be done using qplot?

for a matrix:

```
a<-matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=100)

a[,1]<-1:100
a[,2]<-rnorm(100)
a[,3]<-rnorm(100)

a<-melt(as.data.frame(a),id.vars="V1")
```

ggplot(a,aes(seq_along(a),a))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+facet_wrap(V1)

Comment: This is most emphatically **not** a histogram.  It's a bar plot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `ggplot2` use x as y values and make sequence along x values for the x axis.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x),aes(seq_along(x),x))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

If you have matrix `a` and you need to make plot for each row then melt it and then use `variable` for x axis and `value` for the y axis

```
a<-melt(as.data.frame(a),id.vars=1)

ggplot(a,aes(variable,value))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+facet_wrap(~V1)
```

[image]

Comment: this is perfect, thanks. and what if I have a matrix where I would like to plot each row in a separate plot. Can I use facet_wrap somehow?

Comment: Let's say I have a matrix a, a[,1]=c(1,2,3,4,5,6); a[,2]=runif(6);a[,3]=runif(6). I would like to facet by a[,1] and plot  each row separately. How can I get melt() to produce the correct format? melt(a, id.vars=1:1) doesn't do the job

Comment: Did you get this error using the code I put in the answer? (there is a tilde sign before V1 in facet_wrap)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this too without creating a `dataframe` explicitly:

```
ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=seq_along(x),y=x), stat='identity') + xlab('x') + ylab('y')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution:

```
barplot(x,xlim = c(0,15), ylim = c(0,10))
```

xlim and ylim are scaled, depending on the vector length